# How do you add Decimal Numbers in Bash Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a bash script that will contain random numbers such as 1.2, 3.4, 8.0, 10.9. I want to assign each number to a variable then compute the average.

I've tried doing  `t1=$(( ( RANDOM % 5 ) + 8 ).$(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) ))`
and I get what I want, but I can't figure out how to add them all up then divide to get the average.

Comment: Your title says "How do you get a Random Decimal Number", but it seems that you already have that and that your issue is more like adding and dividing them - if that is true, you should modify your title and probably post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Bash doesn't support floating-point arithmetic. You'll need to manually add up the numbers just like kids do in school. Then do the same for the average.

Comment: @Filkolev: Or use a tool that understands floats, like `bc`.

Comment: @choroba: Or use a shell that does, like Zsh.

Comment: Just got the total using bc

Comment: echo "scale=2; t1+t2" | bc

Comment: Awesome figured it out thank you!!!